# UIImageView fit to maximum width in self sizing tableview cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

What auto layout constraints need to be set so that an image inside a tableview cell expands to the width borders of the cell as in Twitter app?

I can not get it done and wonder which constraints and settings are necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom constraints. Thus `width` will be resized according to the screen width and `height` will be set depending on the aspect ratio of the image, since your cell has dynamic height.

Answer (score 1):

I just focused on the width constraints (leading & trailing), but you can also adjust the other constraints in a similar fashion for top & bottom.

Additionally, you may want to alter your image view to support this, but that will depend upon the image you use. I selected Aspect Fill to make sure it used the entire width. If your image is not properly sized though, this setting will crop the top & bottom of it.

[image]

Notice in the Add New Constraints window that the left & right boxes have a solid red line, which indicates they were selected.

You can adjust the imageView as needed to provide some padding if you want, such as was seen in your linked image as well. The method for setting constraints would still be the same though, just the values in the boxes would differ.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should know that UIImageView in cell is not work as you think when you set the cell's height with 'UITableViewAutomaticDimension'.

If you set the 'height constraint' and change it's value will work.

So, set the 'leading', 'trailing', 'top', 'bottom' and 'height' constraints with your image view

And if your image downloaded, get it's size and do the math and set the 'height constraint' with it.

[image]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "list")

    if let iv = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    {
        // this UIImageView.image(url: URL, placeHolder: UIImage, complete: (UIImage)->()) is my custom function.
        // you can use SDWebImage's function
        iv.image(url: URL(string: "http://imageurl")!, placeHolder: nil, complete: { (img) in

            // calculate imageview's height
            let ivHeight = (iv.frame.size.width * img.size.height) / img.size.width

            // get height constraint and set the value.
            for lc in iv.constraints
            {
                if lc.firstAttribute == .height
                {
                    // this will change cell's height automatically
                    lc.constant = ivHeight
                    break
                }
            }
        })
    }

    return cell!
}
```

Sorry about my bad english. :(